# Addin custom menu in Microsoft Office

Tags: ms-office, ribbon, office-addins

I want to add a custom menu (addin) inside FileMenu after "New" menu in office 2010.

Previously i have the similar add-in for Office 2007 but custumUI.xml has changed for office 2010 and 2013.

I tried required changes but couldn't get the Menu in Office 2010 and 2013.

**Office 2007** :

`<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" onLoad="OnRibbonLoaded" loadImage="GetImage"><ribbon><OfficeMenu><menu id="MenuName" label="&MenuName" insertAfterMso="FileSaveAsMenu" image="menu.png" itemSize="large"`

**Office 2010:** :

`<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="OnRibbonLoaded" loadImage="GetImage"><ribbon><FileMenu><menu id="MenuName" label="&Menuname" insertAfterMso="FileSaveAsMenu" image="menu.png" itemSize="large">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the **backstage** element instead of the ribbon one. For example:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="OnLoad">
  <backstage>    
    <tab id="testArea">
```

You can read more about the Backstage UI in the following articles in MSDN:

- [Introduction to the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691833(v=office.14).aspx)
- [Customizing the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee815851%28v=office.14%29.aspx)